# Quartz scheduler is running twice at same time in cluster environment rarely

Tags: quartz

this issue is not happening all the time. very rarely we are observing same Job is running twice on same node or different node exactly at the same time.

we are using 4 node cluster.

we have already set org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true in quartz.properties
Do we still required to set Annotation Type DisallowConcurrentExecution at Job class level.

we are creating our job classes by implementing interface org.quartz.Job.

Any help is greatly appreciated.